# Is it possible to crawl the stack to get variables?

Tags: c#

I realize that there's never a good reason for doing this, but I'm curious for the purposes of security. Is it possible to crawl the stack and capture variables from different frames?

```
void Func1(string parameter)
{
    Func2(MakeSafeParameter(parameter));
}

// external user code
void Func2(string safeParameter)
{
  // from here could I craw the stack to get Func1's parameter?
}
```

EDIT: From the linked question it appears this isn't directly possible within C# without special references. Thanks for the answers/comments!

Comment: In response to your "never a good reason for doing this" statement, I would imagine it might be helpful in logging errors (assuming it's possible).

Comment: What do you want to hide? if there is something in your code to hide, you can't. Reverse engineering can reveal everything.

Comment: Should `Func1(MakeSafeParameter(parameter));` be `Func2(MakeSafeParameter(parameter));`?

Comment: Visual Studio debugger does it.  So to answer your question: Yes.

Comment: @SamAxe - really? I thought VS was just keeping track of the stack on its way down, not necessarily that it could reach back up and grab additional data.

Comment: @EZI: well.. not *everything*.  It won't reveal xml comments without a pdb file.  Code comments are usually lost forever after compilation.  What I ate for dinner is only recoverable by a forensic scientist.. :)  Whitespace, which is just as important as the code, is completely unrecoverable.

Comment: @AdamV: if you hit a breakpoint and pull up the Call Stack window, then double-click on any item in the call stack window (item == method calls) then you can inspect the state of any variable at that "moment" in time when the method was called.

Comment: @AdamV - code type fixed.

Comment: @Blorgbeard - thanks, didn't find that initially

Comment: @EZI - I'm running user code on the cloud and was just curious if this was possible, it appears to *NOT* be possible without external process/other tools. I specifically wanted to prevent access to certain components that exist on the stack but aren't passed into user code

Comment: @IdiotDeletingMyComments I won't say anything. But you understand it :)

Comment: @EZI I forget what the comment said by now, but I don't recall it being out of line. tough mods.

Comment: @mhand No problem, it was only related with  *Sam Axe*'s digestion problem :)